# Pandas + Matplotlib, Make one color in barplot stand out

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a barplot with different colors. I would like to make one bar stand out with brighter colors and the others faded. My guess is to use the keyword alpha on the bars to fade them, but I can not figure out how to make one keep the original color (= not faded with alpha keyword).
I need help on this
Here is my code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from itertools import cycle, islice
import pandas as pd, numpy as np 



ds2=ds[['Factors', 'contribution']]
ds3=ds2.set_index('Factors')


it = cycle(['b', 'green', 'y', 'pink','orange','cyan','darkgrey'])
my_colors=[next(it) for i in xrange(len(ds))]

figure(1, figsize=(10,8))

# Specify this list of colors as the `color` option to `plot`.
ds3.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, color=my_colors, alpha=0.95)
plt.title('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', fontsize = 10)
```

[image]

Here is my simple dataframe ds3

```
         contribution
Factors              
A            0.188137
B            0.160208
C            0.160208
D            0.151654
E            0.149489
F            0.135975
G            0.063206
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think mgilson's approach is the best were you add the data from Pandas in a Matplotlib command.  You could however also capture the `axes` object which Pandas returns and then iterate over the artists to modify them.

This gets really tricky, because the bars don't have a label (its "_no_legend_") as an identifier, the only way to target a specific bar is to look-up its position in the index of the original `DataFrame`. Any change, like sorting, in the order between plotting and looking it up will give a wrong result!

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'contribution': [0.188137,0.160208,0.160208,0.151654,0.149489,0.135975,0.063206]}
                  ,index=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'])

colors = ['b', 'green', 'y', 'pink','orange','cyan','darkgrey']

ax = df.plot(kind='barh', color=colors, legend=False)

for bar in ax.patches:
    bar.set_facecolor('#888888')

highlight = 'D'
pos = df.index.get_loc(highlight)

ax.patches[pos].set_facecolor('#aa3333')
ax.legend()
```

[image]

So this example gives only a little bit of insight in how Pandas and Matplotlib work together. I don't recommend actually using it and suggest just to go with mgnilson's approach.

Answer (score 3):

Why not plot the special bar in a separate plot command?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

colors = list('rgbkm')
data_y = [1,2,4,5,6]
data_x = [1,1,1,1,1]

ax.barh(data_y, data_x, color=colors, alpha=0.25)

# Plot the special bar separately ...
ax.barh([3], [1], color='b')

plt.show()
```

Comment: I wonder if you could mix a matplotlib [`xkcd`](http://matplotlib.org/xkcd/examples/showcase/xkcd.html) type plot with a standard bar chart... That would *really* emphasize some bars over others...

Comment: @mgilsen, objects are only affected if they are created after `xkdc()`, so if you plot the single bar before and the rest after there wont be a problem. For example: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/RutgerK/7801831

Comment: @RutgerKassies -- Neat.  I really didn't expect that to work.  I don't currently even have maplotlib1.3 installed, so I couldn't play around with it... But I did want to mention it just for fun :).

Comment: Thanks, however do you have any suggestions to how I can integrate this into my code above...

Comment: @jonas -- Unfortunately I'm not at all familiar with pandas... just numpy and matplotlib.  I'll add the pandas tag and see if any of that crowd can chime in here...

Comment: Pandas plotting only wraps matplotlib, you can always fallback on matplotlib if needed. Something like this should work: `ax.barh(ds3.index, ds3, ...`, but i cant be certain without exactly knowing the contents of your `DataFrame`.

Comment: @RutgerKassies -- That's what I would have expected.  I just didn't know how to get the proper data out of the dataframe.  Thanks for chiming in.

Comment: Its just a simple frame of one index column of the letters A-G, and a columns of values, labeled factor in this case

Comment: Doing `ds3.values` will give you a numpy array, i think thats whats happening in the back actually. With an hierarchical `DataFrame` you probably would need to make some sub-selection, but it seems to me that `sheet4` is simple flat data.